# Unable to use ng-if with ng-repeat $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if, md-chip

I'm trying to use ng-if to display a button based on filters being present on screen. I'm using md-chips to show filters in categories.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in sc.filters track by $index">
  <md-chips ng-model="filter.value" ng-if="sc.isArray(filter.value)" md-on-remove="sc.filter()"></md-chips>
</div>
<button ng-if="$first" ng-click="sc.newSearch()">clear filters</button>
```

I track the index and try to add the button if first item was present. It doesn't show the button at all. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$first` should be used within an `ng-repeat` statement. In this case you don't want to use `$first` though.

If you want to add the button if the first item is present, why not just do something like this:

```
<button ng-if="sc.filters.length" ng-click="sc.newSearch()">clear filters</button>
```

Comment: It didn't work at first, i had to tweak it a little bit in my logic to get it working!

Comment: Could you explain what you had to tweak?

Comment: My sc.filters was a complex object. So i had to get its child elements length to get the output i needed.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you were able to get it working!